# Timeseries showing date as month of the year

Tags: python, matplotlib, time-series

I have dataset and I want to visualize timeseries. However, date axis show dates as timestamps. I want it to show like month of the year (Jan-December). How can i format date in timeseries?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO. Please refer to [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: added images thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's a feature that automatically optimizes the x-axis for you. The `matplotlib.dates.AutoDateLocator` [matplotlib.dates.AutoDateLocatoris](https://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html?highlight=dates#module-matplotlib.dates) used. Does your quality match your intentions?

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16,9),dpi=144)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

plt.plot(df.index, df['data'], linestyle='dashed')

locator = mdates.AutoDateLocator()
formatter = mdates.ConciseDateFormatter(locator)

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)

plt.show()
```